# Embed Power BI Report Server report using a single user

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I am looking for a way to embed a report published in on premise Power BI Report Server onto an internal web application. The problem is, not all users of the internal web application has privileges to view the report on the Power BI Report Server. So, I am looking to route the web application user to the Power BI Report using a single user who has all the privileges on the Power BI Report Server.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Kind Regards,
NZM

Comment: That would be working around the built in the authentication mechanism. Give the relevant users privileges in PowerBI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that I already have a mechanism within the web application to manage the large number of users accessing the web application. Now if I have to manage their access in Power BI Server as well, it would be introducing additional maintenance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use PowerBI embedded in the App owns data model and roll the token yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I understand, Power BI Embedded doesn't work with on premise Power BI Report Server and need to have an Azure Active Directory account to work with. Am I mistaken?